# Can we get React localStorage in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

Due to Platform Dependance. React and Node are Host on Separate Domains and are Separate Projects.
Wants to Get React LocalStorage in Nodejs Project

Comment: Please clearer in what you've already tried / thought of

Answer (score 0):

This is a package called [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage). You can try this in your node environment.